# Create Subscription for Room Calendar By Delegated User

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, subscription, office365api

I need to read/write room calendar events. For that, I am using Microsoft Graph Apis. Basically I have delegated one user to read/write events for desired room calendars and using accessToken/refreshToken I can read/write events for any allowed room calendars. Delegated User has following permissions configured at app level:

Calendars.ReadWrite User.Read offline_access Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Files.ReadWrite.All profile openid

Now I want to create a subscription for any event change in any of the room  calendars and here I am facing a challenge. I followed steps mentioned at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_post_subscriptions. It works when I subscribe to delegated users calendar. But when I subscribe for any room calendar, it return 403 error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "fa38673d-47a4-4208-a7c4-b5d2725eac7d",
      "date": "2018-11-19T07:55:32"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this suppose to work like this at all? Do I need more permissions?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

PS: I saw that similar feature is working in GSuite, but not in Office365. Where can I raise a feature request for support in office 365?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and challenge and finally got an answer directly from Microsoft:

It is possible to create a subscription to a shared calendar using application permissions (app-only) with Calendars.Read, but not delegated user permissions.

I created a user voice entry, if you support this please vote:
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36131674-create-microsoft-graph-subscriptions-for-a-shared

Comment: now the link was moved to https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40133578--graphapi-office-365-rest-api-please-add-support

Comment: This link is no more available

Comment: @yosbel 
Can you please share any reference

Comment: @kolbi can you please share any referrence